# How to define a soap webservice name in the url?

Tags: java, spring, soap, jax-ws, spring-boot

I'm creating a `soap` webservice with `spring` and `jax-ws`, and want to define the name of the webservice + the urls explicit:

```
@Component
@WebService(name = "MyService", serviceName = "MyService")
public class MyService {
}
```

When running from within eclipse on tomcat, the path is correct:

```
/services/MyService?wsdl
```

But on a local tomcat installation standalone:

```
/services/My?wsdl
```

Why? Is there anything to consider?

Answer (score 1):

There would be something web service naming conventions. Please refer the below link and check whether you are able to find any answer for your quetion. Correct me if i am wrong

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12461_01/140/retail_soa_enabler_tool_guide/or-rse-Standards.htm

Avoid verbs when naming Web services.Example    Avoid names such as CreateSupplierService.